# Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA Titan V nvidia-396 disables GPU hardware acceleration

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gpu, nvidia-settings

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 [Bionic Beaver] and installed an NVIDIA Titan V GPU for deep learning. I am using NVIDIA-396 as the driver, I am able to run `keras-gpu` neural network libraries explicitly using the GPU.

So, the card and the driver do work for deep learning, although I had to disable *Secure Boot* to make the driver work.

However, my GPU hardware acceleration is disabled and the OpenGL renderer is pointing to `llvmpipe`.

The output of `glxinfo` is:

> OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
>   OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)

`nvidia-smi` shows the presence of the NVIDIA-TITAN-V GPU.
`nvidia-settings` shows an error that

> NO INFO can be found.

Please, I have been struggling with this issue for the past two days and would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Reverted to nvidia-390 driver using run file from NVIDIA website instead of apt install. Worked! Took some time to get here, but the graphics are truly awesome :)